# Struts 2 Portlet - redirectAction not working, doView() not called

Tags: struts2, portlet, websphere-portal, jsr286

I'm trying to create a simple Struts 2 JSR 286 Portlet, running on WebSphere Portal 7. I'm able to display a simple JSP that contains a link which calls an action and displays another JSP which accepts input. That works fine.

I start to run into problems, however, when I try to use a `redirectAction`. I don't see any error messages, but the redirect doesn't seem to work. The Portlet just shows a blank page.

In debugging this I noticed that the `doView` method of my Portlet class is never called, which seems very suspicious.

If anyone has experience developing Struts 2 Portlets on WebSphere Portal, I would appreciate some help in checking that my config files are correct. Have I missed something?

Here are the details:

```
WebSphere Portal 7.0.0.2
WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.25
RAD 8.0.4
Struts 2.3.14.2
Windows 7
```

portlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portlet-app id="com.ibm.demo.jsr286.TopUpPortlet.72594d5fe3" 
version="2.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd">
<portlet>
    <description xml:lang="EN">Demo JSR 286 Struts Portlet</description>
    <portlet-name>Demo Portlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name>Demo Portlet</display-name>

    <!-- DemoPortlet extends org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr286Dispatcher -->
    <portlet-class>com.demo.jsr286.DemoPortlet</portlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <name>viewNamespace</name>
        <value>/view</value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <name>defaultViewAction</name>
        <value>index</value>
    </init-param>

    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>

    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    </supports>

    <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>

    <portlet-info>
        <title>Demo Portlet</title>
        <short-title>DemoPortlet</short-title>
        <keywords>Demo Portlet</keywords>
    </portlet-info>

</portlet>

<default-namespace>http://JSR286StrutsDemo/</default-namespace>
</portlet-app>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>JSR 286 Struts Demo</display-name>

<servlet id="Struts2PortletDispatcherServlet">
    <servlet-name>Struts2PortletDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<include file="struts-plugin.xml"/>

<package name="view" extends="struts-portlet-default" namespace="/view">

    <!-- This action works  -->     
    <action name="index">
        <result>/html/view/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <!-- This action works  -->
    <action name="startDemo">
        <result>/html/view/demo.jsp</result>
    </action>

            <!-- This action does not work  -->
    <action name="redirectToIndex">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">index</param>
            <param name="namespace">/view</param>
            <param name="portletMode">view</param>
        </result>
    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

*** Update ***

I've narrowed the problem down slightly. It looks like the action is being interpreted as a file location rather than a struts action. So, when I call action "redirectToIndex" it tries to display a page called "/view/index.action". I verified this by creating a file with that path and sure enough, the contents of that file are displayed in the portlet.

I feel that I'm probably missing some configuration option, but I'm not sure what. Servlet filter maybe? Can anyone help?

Comment: So what is it? Redirect is not working or method is not getting called? BTW why are you including `struts-plugin.xml` file?

Comment: It's both really. Redirect not working was the first issue, then I noticed that doView wasn't getting called when I was investigating. I'm including struts-plugin.xml because that's where the struts-portlet-default package is defined. Is that not correct?

Comment: There is no need to include it by yourself, because it is already included. Try to give class attribute to your `redirectToIndex` action definition with your action class.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the include and added a class attribute. I created a simple action class that prints a debug message to stdout then returns ActionSupport.SUCCESS. I see the debug message, but the overall behavior is the same.

Comment: So method is executed. Are you seeing your `/html/view/index.jsp` page after that?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing the /html/view/index.jsp page when I call the redirectToIndex action. Instead, the portlet shows an empty page. If I call the index action directly, then it does display /html/view/index.jsp. The DemoPortlet::doView() method isn't called in either case.

Comment: It Struts2 application after all, so forget about `doView` and other portlet methods. Use actions and `Jsr286Dispatcher` as your portlet class.

Comment: Agreed, it is a Struts2 application, but it's also a Portlet. Jsr286Dispatcher inherits from javax.portlet.GenericPortlet, so I thought that if I extend Jsr286Dispatcher and override doView, I could expect that method to be called during the Portlet render phase. Is that not correct?

Comment: Actually you do not need `doView` method, because `Jsr286Dispatcher` is just a dispatcher. You can use actions like in  
ordinary Struts2 application. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need `doView` method, because `Jsr286Dispatcher` is just a dispatcher. You can use actions like in ordinary Struts2 application.

From the documentation:

> The portlet-class element is always org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher (or a subclass, if you have added some custom functionality). This is the portlet that acts as the dispatcher for the Struts 2 framework, and translates incoming user interaction to action requests that Struts 2 understands.

For jsr286 specification `<portlet-class>` should be `org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr286Dispatcher` and `defaultViewAction` init-param will call Struts2 action. And in `struts.xml` file, like usually, you can define action class + method to call.

So you need to define `Jsr286Dispatcher` as `<portlet-class>` and create action which you will use in `struts.xml` action definitions.

Also see this two links: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/struts-2-portlet-tutorial.html and http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/portlet-plugin.html.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Aleksandr. It is much appreciated. I've discovered that the action that I'm trying to redirect to (/view/index.action) is being interpreted as a file location rather than a struts action. I've updated my original post with that information. I'm not sure how to make sure the action gets treated as an action. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using now `Jsr286Dispatcher` instead of your `DemoPortlet`? Also I don't think `FilterDispatcher` is needed in web.xml.